# Template Ref unboxing logic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I'm having trouble creating a reference to an element and storing it inside an (non-reactive) object that I initialize like this:

```js
const myObj = {
  myRef: ref(null),
  ...
}
```

And in the template I have a similar situation:

```html
<template>
   ...
   <Comp :ref="(el) => { myObj.myRef = el }"/>
   ...
</template>
```

Now, if I try to access `myObj.myRef` (after mounting) I get `undefined` ...
I am sure this is due to my lack of understanding of how ref and reactive are unboxed within templates. Can someone explain to me what are the values that I am actually working with within `:ref="..."`?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. `myRef = ref(null)` - this is wrong syntax.  The problem may be in ..., and you may need ... to fix it.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm sorry, it was a miss-type...

Comment: Only **top-level** refs are auto-unwrapped in the template. For others (such as your one in an object) you still need to use `.value`.

Comment: And you shouldn't need function syntax for this case; plain `:ref="myObj.myRef"` should be fine.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes This is exactly what I had missed, thanks! I wrote [an example](https://shorturl.at/ehxJZ) of my full implementation, can you tell me if this is the right way, or am I using some function improperly?

Comment: Or if there are more compact ways, as you suggested in your second answer! It was suggested that I use `defineExpose` when working with components, to avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Only *top-level* refs are auto-unwrapped in the template.** For others (such as your one in an object) you still need to use `.value`.

> Can someone explain to me what are the values that I am actually working with within `:ref="..."`?

These are the docs: [Vue Guide - Template Refs: Function Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs).

```html
<Comp :ref="(el) => { myObj.myRef = el }"/>
```

`el` is an element reference or component instance:

> The function receives the element reference as the first argument.

In this case, it is a component reference (see my note at the end of this answer).

`myObj.myRef` is a ref, *not auto-unwrapped* (because it is not top-level). Hence, the ref *itself* gets overwritten, not its value. If you want to use this approach, you can set the ref using `myObj.myRef.value = el`.

> Now, if I try to access `myObj.myRef` (after mounting) I get `undefined`.

I'm not quite sure what's happening here, especially since you haven't shown this code. Accessing `myObj.myRef` verbatim should give you the component instance (as you overwrote the ref with the reference). However, I suspect that you are actually using `.value` (`myObj.myRef.value`), which logically yields `undefined`, given that a component instance has no `value` property by default (you could expose one, if you wanted to).

---

Since you seem to be simply binding the reference to your ref, you don't need the function syntax. You can just use the following instead:

```html
<Comp :ref="myObj.myRef"/>
```

Note the fact that I am *binding* it now, not just passing the name (`:ref` vs `ref`). This is required because it includes a property access and is therefore not just a name.

However, I suspect that this is a simplified example and that there is more going on than this.

---

Now, in the comments you gave a full implementation and asked if could be improved.

(As I guessed earlier, there is more detail than in your question: you are actually accessing and saving an exposed ref on component, not just saving the reference itself.)

So, let's see what you're trying to accomplish:
**You appear to want to have access to a template ref internal to a component.**

Your current implementation does this by

- creating a template ref in the component,
- exposing it (with `defineExpose`),
- creating an otherwise-plain ref in the parent,
- binding a *function* to the `ref` attribute of the component, which saves the exposed template ref to the other ref.

Here's what we've got so far (given the implementation you linked to in the comments):

`Comp.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const el = ref(null);

defineExpose({ inner: el });
</script>

<template>
  <p ref="el">Phrase one</p>
  <p>Phrase two</p>
</template>
```

`App.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const msg = {
  ref: ref(null)
}

function logMe() {
  console.log(msg.ref.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logMe">Log the First one</button>
  <Comp :ref="(el) => { msg.ref.value = el ? el.inner : undefined }" />
</template>
```

[Playground 1](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

The component is fine, but the parent can be simplified quite a lot by using a computed ref instead of a function `ref` binding.

The changes:

- Import `computed`:

  ```js
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
  ```
- Create a template ref for the component itself:

  ```js
  const comp = ref(null)
  ```

  You can use whatever name you wish, as long as you use the same one in the template.
- Change the `ref` property of `msg` from a plain ref to a computed:

  ```js
  computed(() => comp.value?.inner ?? null)
  ```

  This creates a computed ref where the value will be the exposed ref `inner` of the component if present, else `null`.
- Then we simply bind the template ref for the component to the component:

  ```html
  <Comp ref="comp" />
  ```

These changes yield this:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const comp = ref(null)

const msg = {
  ref: computed(() => comp.value?.inner ?? null)
}

function logMe() {
  console.log(msg.ref.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logMe">Log the First one</button>
  <Comp ref="comp" />
</template>
```

[Playground 2](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Although this is actually two lines *longer* (the extra ref and blank line), it is much *simpler*. Instead of mutating an object in a function handler for a `ref` binding, there is a just a computed ref accessing the exposed property.

This is of course all rather subjective. You may prefer the function binding, or the function approach but extracted to a method. Etc.

---

Note that [a template ref for a component is that component's *component instance*](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component):

> `ref` can also be used on a child component. In this case the reference will be that of a component instance.

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but I felt that this was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Only top-level refs are auto-magically unwrapped inside templates.

Your ref function will be called and will replace your ref altogether on mount. Trying to access `.value` on that would in all likelihood result in `undefined`.

If you want the behavior you described, you'd want `:ref="(el) => { myObj.myRef.value = el }"`.

You can use the binding syntax, as others have suggested: `:ref="myObj.myRef"`.

DOM refs are a bit tricky to work with, so I'll recommend an alternative method (that I personnaly use):

- Have a top-level ref for each DOM element you want to reference, then you'll be able to use names directly and have all the advantages that come with that
- Group them in an object later if you so desire
- Potentially use `reactive` around that object to have something nicer to work with

That would give you:

```
const compRef = ref();

const obj = reactive({
  // [...]
  compRef,
  // [...]
});

<Comp ref="compRef" />
```

Comment: The function is only called when the element is mounted or unmounted, so the first call will be when the component mounts. The argument will _never_ be `undefined`; only a element reference, component instance, or `null`.